# c++ local variable gets overwritten (but only on some notebook)

Tags: c++, qt

I am facing some strange behaviour appearing only on some notebook.
I am developing in c++ using msvc 2012 and the qt framework.

I will try to sum up the problem and i am hoping that someone has any idea what the problem could be or what i could try to find out..

Generally it's the following problem:

```
void myclass::foo() 
{
    const double value1 = 100.0;
    double value2;

    value2 = some_function_returning_double();

    if(value1 > value2)
    {
         //__ do something
    }
}
```

The problem is that the condition fails as the local variable gets overwritten.
If I do some debug output i can see that variable value1 is not 100.0 anymore but some random value .. so that the comparison randomly fails ..

One thing i figured out is that everything just works fine if i don't use local variables. If i set up value1 and value2 as member variables of my class everything works without problems, but that can't be the solution.

Now the strange thing is that this error does only occur on some notebook (some mobile i5 cpu).
On my machine (i5) and on many other notebooks (even other mobile i5) everything just works fine.

I know that you won't be able to solve my problem with this little information i can offer here, but maybe some of you has any hint what the problem could be and what i could try to solve this.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `some_function_returning_double` appears to be the culprit. It overruns the stack and corrupt the variables of parent(caller) function. Debugging this function or putting a watchpoint on value1 may help. A UB can give different results on different targets.

Comment: Sounds like UB. Plese post an [SSCCE](http://www,sscce.org).

Comment: This may happen when you are tired or have been trying to debug the problem for too much time. I'd suggest you to go walk for a while and then get back to it. Also, do not underestimate `some_function_returning_double()`.

Comment: in vs2012, add a data breakpoint (debug->new breakpoint->new data breakpoint) on the addresse of the variable that gets overwritten. It will break just after the value has been modified, and you should see the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

In visual studio 2012, add a data breakpoint (debug->new breakpoint->new data breakpoint) on the address of the variable that gets overwritten.

First, break at the start of the function.
Then set the data breakpoint: just type `&value1` in the "New breakpoint` the input box.

Then it should break just after the value has been modified, and you should see the culprit.

Data breakpoints are a very powerful tool, that helped me found nasty bugs very quickly.